# 「～たのは」という文型は何という意味？

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

What is the meaning of ～たのは? For context, the song bluebird by いきものがかり says

> 目指したのは青い青いあの空.

Answer (score 4):

「の」＝「もの」or「こと」.

「[目指]{めざ}したの」＝「目指したもの」

「の」 is a nominalizer; It nominalizes the preceding verb or adjective.

「目指したの」= "what I/we ran toward" = "my/our destination"

Other examples: 「[赤]{あか}いのがほしい。」= "I want a red one."

「[行]{い}きたいのは[京都]{きょうと}です。」= "Where/The place I want to go to is Kyoto, (not another town)."

Comment: But so when nominalizing something with た at the end, isn't there an added meaning? I know with たもの　that implies some nostalgia, right?

Comment: @Anonymous 目指した in 目指したのは/目指したものは is the past tense form. The present tense form would be 目指すのは or 目指すものは.